# iOS touches to device's viewport x/y coordinates via Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, touch, viewport

I am currently developing a webpage for an iPhone which contains a DIV element that the user can touch and drag around.  In addition, when the user drags the element to the top or bottom of the device's screen, I want to automatically scroll the page up or down.

The problem I am having is trying to determine a reliable formula to get the coordinates in the onTouchMove event that coorespond with the user's finger reaching the top or the bottom of the device viewport.  My current formula seems tedious and I feel there may be an easier way to do this.

My current formula to determine if the touch event has reached the bottom of the screen:

```
function onTouchMoveHandler(e)
{
    var orientation=parent.window.orientation;
    var landscape=(orientation==0 || orientation==180)?true:false;
    var touchoffsety=(!landscape?screen.height - (screen.height - screen.availHeight):screen.width - (screen.width - screen.availWidth)) - e.touches[0].screenY + (window.pageYOffset * .8);
    if(touchoffsety < 40) alert('finger is heading off the bottom of the screen');
}
```

I have done a bit of Javascript reflection on objects such as the window, document, body, e.touches to see if I could find a set of numbers that would always add up to equal the top or bottom of the screen, but without reliable success.  Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a link with an in-depth explanation of different mobile platforms and Javascript variables describing the viewport dimensions, and how much they can differ from each other.  This helped me find the answer: http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `screenY` field of a touch holds the y coordinate relative to the screen-top regardless of current scroll position, your current calculation does not make a whole lot of sense to me. I hope I did not misunderstand what your trying to do.

To find out if a touch is close to the top or the bottom of the device, I would first check if screenY is close to top (top being 0), since you can work with that value directly. Then, if it's not close to top, calculate how close it is to the bottom and check that.

```
var touch = e.touches[0];
if (touch.screenY < 50)
{
    alert("Closing in on Top");
}
else //Only do bottom calculations if needed
{
    var orientation=parent.window.orientation;
    var landscape=(orientation==0 || orientation==180)?true:false;
    //height - (height - availHeight) is the same as just using availHeight, so just get the screen height like this
    var screenHeight = !landscape ? screen.availHeight : screen.availWidth;
    var bottomOffset = screenHeight - touch.screenY; //Get the distance of the touch from the bottom
    if (bottomOffset < 50)
        alert("Closing in on Bottom");
}
```

Comment: That's one of the problems I've ran across.  One would have thought screenY is all you need, but that is not the case.  One reason is because if you have two iFrames, and are dragging a DIV in the bottom iFrame, the numbers seem to skew depending on how far down you are currently scrolled.  That's where the window.pageYOffset comes into play, it tells how far down the browser window is scrolled.  But depending on where it is scrolled to, it seems to over or under compensate for the correct amount.  That's why I fudged it with multiplying it by .8, but it still is finicky.

Comment: Did you try clientY? Maybe this will help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885808/includes-touch-events-clientx-y-scrolling-or-not

Comment: When I get back in the office after newyears, I will try the article you referenced.  That looks promising.  The fact that this may be a bug would make sense, and this guy may have figured out the bug and how to work around it...

Comment: The article was not of any help.  But you may be onto something with screenY.  I am testing with an iPad right now and found that screenY is the screen coordinate from the top of the browser where the address bar ends.  If you touch on or above the address bar, you actually get a NEGATIVE screenY value.  The screen.availHeight includes the address bar size, thus giving me grief.  However, I found that window.outerHeight does not include the address bar.  So the formula window.outerHeight - touch.screenY seems to work to find touches approaching the bottom.  I'll test the iphone tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually not bad. You could also use Zepto.js and its built-in touch events and `.offset()` method to get it a little easier:

- http://zeptojs.com/#touch
- http://zeptojs.com/#offset

However, I'm interested to know whether or not you actually manage to get it scrolling at the bottom, and if the performance is smooth enough to make the effect worthwhile. (frequently scrolling in iOS interrupts JavaScript really hard)

Comment: I have it working pretty well on an iPad 1 using window.outerHeight - touch.screenY < 40.  I am using a setTimeout at 20 milliseconds scrolling by setting the .scrollTop parameter incremented by 20 pixels each time.  I'm also moving the div that your finger is holding onto by the same amount so it appears to not move while the background scrolls.  The performance is actually pretty smooth.