# THREE.js Ray Intersect fails by adding canvas to div on mobile

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to add my canvas to a div-container, so I had to make some changes to my raycasters vectors:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
```

to

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(((event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft)//renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1, -((event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop) / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
```

as seen in:
[THREE.js Ray Intersect fails by adding div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/)

It works perfectly on desktop, but fails on mobile (iPhone 4s and Nexus 5).
In my eyes there's nothing wrong with the calculation, so what am I missing?

Comment: I haven't checked your vector calculation but on some mobile devices `event.clientX/Y` are [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885808/includes-touch-events-clientx-y-scrolling-or-not).